# Is there a way to stop tripping?

Tags: roblox

If you play [Roblox](https://www.roblox.com) you know there is a game mechanic called tripping. It is not anything fancy; you fall on the floor, your character flops around for a bit, and then gets back up. If you play [Roblox](https://www.roblox.com), then you know this is REALLY annoying. I would like to disable it, if possible, because other players make obstacle courses and if you trip you fall into the void and it can be really annoying at some times. Is it possible to disable tripping?

Comment: I don't think you can. I think that it's just part of the game's mechanics.

Comment: I agree with @Alex, it is a game mechanic.  People make certain maps just to exploit this mechanic and challenge other players to essentially - not trip.

Comment: @Mumford451 Oh ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Roblox "tripping" feature cannot be removed as this is a game mechanic.  The developers added this function and players take advantage of it by creating maps just to try and trip and [usually] kill you because of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can only remove game mechanics in your own Place. Like say, Pokèmon Brick Bronze; it has coding that removes jumping, except for in the fire-type Gym (obby).

Comment: You've contributed a number of low quality posts today.  Here at Arqade, we try to ensure that we have a higher level of quality than most sites around.  To that end, if you continue to post content that shows no effort or doesn't add anything new, the system will automatically prevent you from posting anything at all.  If you would like to continue contributing, then it's a good idea to put more effort into your contributions.

Comment: I edited it to say yes. I was looking back at Pokèmon Brick Bronze.

Comment: PS why'd the editor use a link to the Roblox website?