# How do I prevent being launched into the air?

Tags: roblox

When I play *Natural Disaster Survival* in Roblox, sometimes I get launched into the air by an earthquake or a meteor shower. It's very annoying as getting launched eventually kills me and doesn't let me get the survival. Is there a setting to turn off the launching? If there isn't, is there a way to prevent it?

**Also:** Is this *[launching into the air](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283702/is-there-a-way-to-stop-tripping)* a game mechanic or something like tripping in Roblox?

Comment: its cause roblox physics are totally screwed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roblox is not known for being a flawless game, this happens a lot in roblox and i have never been able to fix it or find someone who has fixed it.

Comment: Something like that, yes. I'm playing for survival and then I get launched high up into the air.

Comment: ok there is no way to turn this off

Comment: No problem, can you mark the answer correct so i know i helped?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and i am glad i could help you.